# how to increase contrast of font using css where the dropdown is disabled

Tags: css

how to increase contrast of font using css with a disabled dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select:disabled {
  color:#fff;
  background:#000;
}
```

Just setting the color and background for the disabled state worked for me in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Demo: http://codepen.io/Grilly86/pen/LWzExe

Do you see problems in some other browsers?

**Edit: For Safari (Mac and iOS) you probably also have to set `-webkit-text-fill-color`.**